# grails view parameters bind with non domain class

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I want to bind view page params to non domain class(say *.java class).

```
Project projectInstance = new Project(params)
```

where Project is not Domain class, it is simply java class.

Does grails provide any plugin or any way to bind it to non domain class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cand try with bindData.

In controler:

```
Project project = new Project()
bindData(project, params)
```

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for. Thanks.